# what are the steps in object detection?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

I'm new to image processing and I want to do a project in object detection. So help me by suggesting a step-by-step procedure to this project. Thanx.

Comment: Your question is too broad, therefore you probably won't get any satisfying answer. It's like asking "I want to prepare food, can you tell me a step by step procedure?". There are already several questions on SO about image-processing introductions and books.

Answer (score 3):

Object detection is a very complex problem that includes some real hardcore math and long tuning of parameters to the computation methods involved. Your best bet is to use some freely available library for that - Google will help.

Answer (score 3):

There are lot of algorithms about the theme and no one is the best of all. It's usually a mixture of them what makes the best solution to the solution.
For example, for object movement detection you could look at *frame differencing* and *misture of gaussians*.
Also, it's very dependent of your application, the environment (i.e. noise, signal quality), the processing capacity you may have available, the allowable error margin...

Besides, for it to work, most of time it's first necessary to do some kind of image processing to the input data like median filter,  sobel filter, contrast enhancement and a large so on.

I think you should start reading all you can: books, google and, very important, a lot of papers about the subjects (there are many free in internet) you are interested in.

And first of all, i think it's fundamental (at least it has been for me) having a good library for testing. The one i have used/use is OpenCV. It's very complete, implement many of the actual more advanced algorithms, is very active, has a big community and it's free.
[Open Computer Vision Library (OpenCV)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/)

Have luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/). It's nowhere near [Project Natal's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Natal) levels of accuracy or usefulness, but it does give you the tools to learn the algorithms easily. It's an image processing and AI library and there are several tutorials on [colored object tracking](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/lego_pan_tilt_camera/) and [motion detection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx).

Another one to look at is [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) from Intel. I believe it's a bit more advanced, but it's written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It might get you started in this complex field. The algorithm pages that it links to are interesting reading.

http://sun-valley.stanford.edu/projects/helicopters/final.html

Comment: The link is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[This lecture](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-2500845581503718756&q=jeff+hawkins) by Jeff Hawkins, will give you an idea about the state of the art in this super-difficult field.

Seems that video disappeared... but [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvGHL4-LbLw) should cover similar ground.